# Correct way to play <audio> + <video> from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm getting different results i Firefox and Chrome when using <audio> and <video> with preload="none" and then trying to play from Javascript.

Let's say i was using preload="auto" or preload="metadata" :

```
audio.src = "filename";
audio.play();
```

That seems to work fine in both Firefox and Chrome but i want to use preload="none" and then Chrome dossent play.

So i'm trying this code with preload="none" :

```
audio.src = url;

audio.load();

audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
   audio.play(); // For some reason this dossent work in Firefox
}, false);

audio.play(); // Added this so Firefox would play
```

I don't know if that's the correct way to do it.

I'm using :
Firefox 20.0.1
Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m

I made a demo : http://netkoder.dk/test/test0217.html

**Edit :**

In the 2nd audio player (on the demo page) it seems that when using preload="none" you have to use load().
But is it correct to just use play() right after load() or is the correct way to use an event to wait for the file to load before playing it ?

In the 3rd audio player it seems Firefox 20.0.1 dossent support the canplay event correctly when used with addEventListener() because it dossent trigger after load(), it triggers after play() and also triggers when scrubbing though the sound which dossent seem to be the way the canplay should work.
Using .oncanplay does work.

So the following code seems to work :

```
  function afspil2(url) {

     afspiller2.src = url;
     afspiller2.load(); // use load() when <audio> has preload="none"
     afspiller2.play();

  }

  function afspil3(url) {

     afspiller3.src = url;
     afspiller3.load(); // use load() when <audio> has preload="none"

     //afspiller3.addEventListener('canplay', function() { // For some reason this dossent work correctly in Firefox 20.0.1, its triggers after load() and when scrubbing
     //   afspiller3.play();
     //}, false);

     afspiller3.oncanplay = afspiller3.play(); // Works in Firefox 20.0.1

  }
```

I updated the demo to include the changes : http://netkoder.dk/test/test0217.html

My way of adding addEventListener inside the afspil3() function dossent seem good because the first time the function is called the code inside addEventListener is called 1 time. The second time the function is called the code inside addEventListener is called 2 time and then 3 times and so on.

Comment: Can you provide a full example of where you're setting `preload="none"` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Demo : http://netkoder.dk/test/test0217.html

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `audio` tags are missing the required `src` attribute, or `<source>` tags. When I added them in your demo, all 3 players immediately began working in both Chrome and FF.

Also, I recently discovered that `src` cannot be an empty string and subsequently changed with JS. If there's a reason you can't set the `src` in the HTML, your best alternative, IMO, is to create the `audio` elements with Javascript:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = url;
audio.controls = true;
audio.preload = false;
// and so on
```

**Edit:** Ok. It seems that in Chrome, when the HTML is `preload="none"` it is necessary to call `load()` before playing when the `src` is changed. Your second `audio` doesn't preload, so your function needs to be this:

```
  function afspil2(url) {
     afspiller2.src = url;
     afspiller2.load(); // add load call
     afspiller2.play();
  }
```

Then, it seems that in Firefox, it is necessary to set `preload="auto";` when attaching an event to the `canplay` event, like in the 3rd function.

```
  function afspil3(url) {
     afspiller3.src = url;
     afspiller3.preload = "auto";
     afspiller3.load();
     afspiller3.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
        this.play(); // For some reason this dossent work in Firefox
     }, false);
  }
```

That just seems very strange, but I tested it multiple times, and each time it would play if `preload="auto"` is called, but would not play if it isn't called. Note that it wasn't necessary for the 2nd player, which was also `preload="none"` in the HTML tag.

Finally, Chrome has some odd behaviors if there are multiple `<audio>` elements on the page. For all three players, reloading the page and clicking "the big electron" link would play correctly.

Reloading and then clicking "Yoda" on the 2nd or 3rd player won't do anything, but it WILL play for the first player. But, if the top player is played first by any means - play button or either link - then the other two "Yoda" links will suddenly work.

Also, if you click a 2nd or 3rd "Yoda" link first after reload, and then click the top player, the previously clicked "Yoda" (that didn't previously play) will begin to play on its own after the top player stops.

Suffice it to say they have some bugs to work out.

Comment: Adding a src does play that file if starting the audio player but my Javascript code still doesn't work after that if you try changing the audio source via the links above the player.

Comment: @scootergrisen Just added an edit. Man, HTML5 `<audio>` is just not yet where it needs to be. I actually ran your HTML through W3C validator because I thought maybe multiple IDs or something could explain the crazy behavior. Nope, no errors. It just isn't well developed yet.

Comment: It's ok that's it's not developed yet and not working in all browsers, i like living on the edge :D But i would like to know what the correct way to do it is.

Comment: load() fixes the 2nd audio player. And yes Chrome has some strange issues but that's not a problem i just want to know how the correct way to write the code is. Meaning the standard W3C way even if it not working properly in browsers right now. Anyway i just found out that Firefox dossent seem to support the canplay event when used with addEventlistener() but it does support the oncanplay event.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in my opinion would mean using an existing solution, like http://mediaelementjs.com/

If your really interested in the details on the best way to play audio and video with js then look at the source: 
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/tree/master/src/js

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/me-mediaelements.js

Comment: There is a commented out section starting with "Chrome now supports preload="none"" at https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/build/mediaelement-and-player.js so maybe that's a hint that there could still be some problems. The code I'm writing is for other people to see on my website so I don't want to use code like mediaelementjs.

Comment: With mediaelementjs you get full support for even old browsers, and most would use that instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. You should atleast add a link to your page to mediaelementjs as an (imo: better) alternative.

Comment: Thats fine that you think its better but thats not what im looking for. I want to know how to code it myself from the bottom and i dont mind it not working in old browsers or even all the new ones.